# Output PDF should only be part of the page

Tags: pdftex, pdf, crop, pdfcrop

I have a paper that was accepted and now I have to convert my Latex document to their style. All of it is hidden inside the document class.
An example code is of the form

```
\documentclass{ws-m3as}

\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

and one can download the [ws-m3as](https://www.worldscientific.com/page/m3as/stylefiles-readme-2e) file here.
The output is of the following form:

> [image]

You see there are these lines on the page boundary. This area will be cut away in the online and printed version. I was asking myself if there a command of the kind

```
\cropallpages{2cm,2cm,1cm,1cm}
```

where I can give the height (above, below) and width (left,right) that should be cut away in the output file (PDF). Then I can try around which exact length I need. I want to get in the end

> [image]

like it will be in the online and printed version.

Comment: Without further data (exact journal, where do we find the style, an example article, ...) it is *very* hard to help you.

Comment: @vonbrand I included it, thank you for the comment.

Comment: Please. "One of the leading scientific publishers in the world" has a support department (email addresses are on the page you linked). Please ask there.

Comment: @MartinSchröder True, I can do that, thank you. I think it is still an interesting question, in a more general situation where the output pdf should be cropped. Or do you think this is not really feasible?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the editor that will crop the page. I think it more likely that the journal's printer will physically crop the page. Try printing and then cropping the physical pages according to the trim marks.

Comment: @PeterWilson Not necessarily since the online version one can download on the journal page is also the cropped version.  In the post-processing step it is easy to crop the pages, I just use Preview of MacOS. I was wondering if Latex can do it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can crop a page. But I'm too lazy now to calculate the correct values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pdfpagesattr
{ /CropBox [150 150 300 400] }
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: If someone is interested, the exact values are /CropBox [66 53 546 768]